# jquery smooth scroll to div - strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a web page which has a fixed header, and 3 main divs one below the other. One of the links in the header is made to smooth scroll to the last div. The scrolling works on first click, but when I click again, it scrolls to the top of page. So, basically it is behaving like a toggle. First click scrolls to div, next click scrolls to top of page.

The code I have is:

```
var targetOffset = $('#targetDiv').offset().top - 75;
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 700);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you calculate the `targetOffset` on every click. Maybe this could work:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var targetOffset = $('#targetDiv').offset().top - 75;
  $('#theLink').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 700);
  });
});
```